# In java if I extend a class and don't use a super field while redefining every function does the field still uses memory?

Tags: java, memory

In java if I extend a class and don't use a super field while redefining every function does the field still uses memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fields are still there. Primitive fields use the memory they need (e.g. 32 bits for `int`s), reference fields ("object pointers") take 32 bits even if they're null. The fields have to be there even if they're not actively used, because the compiler has no way to be sure whether *someone* is going to need them.

Comment: Nit pick, there are rare cases where it would be theoretically possible to prove that the fields are not needed; i.e. if the fields are all private, and all the constructors / methods that access them are not used / overridden in the subclass.  But this is so rare that it is not worth addressing.  (Besides, there is still the issue of reflective access to the fields.)

Comment: You're right, but reflection indeed renders access modifiers merely informative.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the field still consumes memory.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! It defaultly comes to the child class and occupies memory.!